# How to load local html page in electron <webview>

Tags: electron

I am trying to load a local html page with an electron webview tag. Problem is I can not figure out the correct path. I assume this must be a relative path.

Loading an external http://... file is no problem.

Relative path like : 
"src=/frames/something.html" is not working

Answer (score 4):

Try prefixing the path with `file://`, and never use relative paths since they'll break when the app is packaged, instead build absolute paths using `__dirname`.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed `__dirname` is needed to load local file. Thanks.

With a Handlebars template I got it working.

In app.js

`var fname = 'file://' + __dirname + '/windows/webview.html';`

`var context = '<webview src=' +'"' + fname + '"' + '</webview>';`